# avconv recording pulseaudio output monitor stretches audio

Tags: audio, pulse-audio, libav

Recording audio from pulseaudio output monitor results in stretched audio:

- The audio falls out of sync as it moves slower than the video

  - I've checked, the video is in sync, it's the audio that's the problem
- The audio pitch is lower as it's been stretched.
- This only happens with the output monitor, microphones are synced perfectly
- Debian sid

Demo code:

```
avconv -f pulse -i alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor -acodec copy out.wav
```

Where `alsa[...]monitor` is the name of the monitor of audio output as defined in `pactl list`

The speed difference between video and audio is almost exactly the same ratio as the difference between the `48000 Hz` that avconv automatically chooses as the stream frequency and the `44100 Hz` that `pactl list short sources` says it's supposed to be.

Adding the `-ar 44100` flag to avconv makes no difference, the audio is still stretched wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently pulseaudio doesn't know what it wants. It tells everyone it's using 48khz when it's really using 44.1khz.

The fix:

Uncomment `default-sample-rate = 44100` in `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` and set it to `48000`